# Wake up a Windows 7 PC using Remote Desktop

Tags: wake-on-lan

I had a PC with Windows Server 2003 installed; it was used as file/movies server at home. I was able to wake it up from a different PC (running Windows 7) just by running Remote Desktop and connecting to the server.

When I upgraded the server to Windows 7 Ultimate, I lost the ability to wake it up with Remote Desktop on the client end. The hardware and BIOS settings are exactly the same.

These were/are my settings:

**Windows:**

- NIC setup to wakeup the PC
- Disabled "Allow ONLY Magic Packet"

**NIC config:**

- Accept Magic Packets + Patterns (or something similar)
- Shutdown/Restart  - Enabled

**BIOS:**

- ACPI 2.0 - enabled
- APIC Support - Enabled

How can I restore the previous behavior? I really want to be able to wake the server up using Remote Desktop.

Comment: Have you tried a different program than remote desktop to send the magic packet to wake the target PC?  Maybe there was a setting in RD which you lost new that you (I assume) had to change the connection settings file for RD.

Comment: I have tried a little utility called WakeOnLanGui.

with this one, I am able to wake up the NAS.

The optimum for me would be to STILL be able to wake the NAS JUST using RD as I use to do before with win 2003 server.

In the RD settings.... there are no differences.
I run RD from my personal PC....so the settings have always been the same.
Only the OS on the target NAS has changed.
Even the IP address is the same....